# Skyrim-Disenchanting

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

not sure how to word this so i will use an example.

Lets say i disenchant a weapon that dose 5 points of stamina damage. i will be able to add that effect to other weapons but the effect in my enchantment table will say "5 points of stamina damage"

dose this restrict my potential for the enchantment at all?

Like if i disenchanted a weapon that dose 20 points of stamina damage instead will my enchantments then be more powerful? or is the power of the effect based purely on your skill and spent perks in the skill?

Comment: Sorry, have to repost. Cant find duplicate but it depends on how high your enchantment skill is. If destroyed weapon has 6 points of stamina damage you only learn the enchantment off the weapon when destroyed. Depends on what soul gem your using too. Strenth of skill u put on somthing depends on how high your enchantment tree is.

Comment: Yeah I also assume not because if they were truly two different effects, you could disenchant both the 5 points and the 20 points for two different enchantments, right?